# How to Validate Date Period Cross over with Other Date periods in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a list that stores information about client hospitalization. One client may have multiple hospitalization details, each with a with time period (a hospitalization start date and discharge date).

If I add new hospitalization information with a time period, I need to validate that the newly added date does not cross over with any of the clients' existing time periods. Are there any existing JavaScript validations to do this?

Comment: Are you expecting a code to check the input date within a range ?

Comment: No, i need the code for the Comparison of date range with date range. like if iam added one information from 1 april to 20 april.. then again if i add April 5 to april 7, it should restrict..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in validation, But you easily can write such validation on your own. For example:

```
function periodOverlaps(testPeriod, periods) {
    for (var i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
        var period = periods[i];
        if (period.start < testPeriod.start && period.end > testPeriod.start)
            return true;
        if (period.start > testPeriod.start && period.start < testPeriod.end)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var periods = [{
        start : new Date('1/1/2015'),
        end : new Date('1/3/2015')
    }, {
        start : new Date('1/5/2015'),
        end : new Date('1/7/2015')
    }
];

var testPeriod = {
    start : new Date('1/2/2015'),
    end : new Date('1/3/2015')
};

periodOverlaps(testPeriod, periods);
```